# Access specific bean from a list in jstl

Tags: jstl

I am trying to access a bean from a list of beans at a specific index (which varies for each function call).
I can do it with a static number like ${fruits[0].name}.
But trying to access it like ${fruits[x].name}, where in var x is received in the javascript function, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is executed on client side while JSTL is done on server side. So it is not possible to pass variables of JavaScript to JSTL.

You may have to use Ajax, WebSocket or get all variables needed by client side on server side.